# Understanding this conditional expectation on a filtered probability space

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Y_t,\ t=1,\dots T,$ be i.i.d. on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Let $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(Y_1,\dots,Y_t)$. Let $Q$ be equivalent to $P$ and let $\frac{dQ}{dP}=(S_T)^C$ where $S_t=\Pi^t_{u=1}\exp(Y_u)$ and $C$ is a constant.
In the given solution to a practice question with these assumptions, I found the following expression:
$$E_Q[S_{t+1}|\mathcal{F}_t]=\frac{E_P[S_{t+1}(S_T)^C|\mathcal{F}_t]}{E_P[(S_T)^C|\mathcal{F}_t]}=S_t\frac{E_P[e^{Y_{t+1}}e^{CY_{t+1}}]}{E_P[e^{CY_{t+1}}]}$$I am familiar with the change of measure in the expectation using Radon-Nikodym derivative, however I am confused about dividing by the expectation of the Radon-Nikodym derivative. Supposedly this has to do with Bayes Theorem, and its normalizing constant but I do not know how that works with expectation in this setting. I would appreciate it if somebody could explain this part to me.

In the second equality I understand that we can pull out the $S_t$ from $S_{t+1}$ as $S_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable and we are left with $e^{Y_{t+1}}$, but I am having difficulties understanding why the other exponents only have $e^{CY_{t+1}}$ left. Again I understand that all the exponents from $Y_1$ to $Y_t$ can be pulled out and then they cancel out, but where are the exponents from $Y_{t+2}$ until $Y_T$? These are not $\mathcal{F}_t$-measurable but somehow they are not there anymore. Maybe I am overlooking something obvious, but I would again appreciate it if someone could clear up my confusion. Thank you!